# Orange doesn't work well on 4k screen

Tags: orange

I'm running Orange 3.3 on a 4k display (laptop) with Windows 10.
Orange is not scaling and shows as a very tiny application interface. 
I have (and know that I can) scale my entire desktop - but, is there a scaling option (other than scaling my whole desktop)?

If not, this is something Orange devs should look into.

Comment: You can instruct Windows to run a program in an upscaled 96dpi mode: right-click the program shortcut, go Properties and check "Disable Display Scaling on High DPI settings"

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. I tried this, and it had no effect.

Comment: It looks ugly on retina Macs, too. I think this is because Orange still uses Qt 4. Migration to Qt 5 is planned -- there are already some patches on Github.

Comment: Thanks JanezD. I'll be sure to look for any updates.

Comment: maybe try this

1.   Right click Orange Icon,
 2.   Select Properties,
  3.  Compatibility Tab
   4.  Under Settings Section check Override High DPI scaling behaviour. Scaling performed by. Select System.
   5. Then Apply or Ok